# Dismiss Keyboard from Another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I'm using [SJSegmentedViewController](https://github.com/subinspathilettu/SJSegmentedViewController) to make my view controller segmented.

I have one view controller named as `PlaceReviewsVC` where I have added textView for review. For post this review I'm adding `Post` bar button instance of `UIBarButtonItem` at `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` in my `placeDetailSegmentController` which are instance of `SJSegmentedViewController`.

Now issue is when I click on post button, I'm not able to dismiss keyboard.

I have tried following code to add post button in segmented view controller.

```
let headerVC = PlaceImagesVC.viewController()

let reviewVC = PlaceReviewsVC.viewController()
reviewVC.delegate = self
reviewVC.title = "Reviews"

let placeDetailSegmentController = SJSegmentedViewController()     
placeDetailSegmentController.delegate = self
placeDetailSegmentController.title = "Pedal Studio"
placeDetailSegmentController.headerViewController = headerVC
placeDetailSegmentController.segmentControllers = [reviewVC]
placeDetailSegmentController.headerViewHeight = 280
placeDetailSegmentController.selectedSegmentViewHeight = 2.0
placeDetailSegmentController.selectedSegmentViewColor = .white

let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "icon_back").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
button.tintColor = .white
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(backButtonTapped), for:.touchUpInside)
button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

placeDetailSegmentController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton            

let btnPost = UIButton(type: .custom)
btnPost.setTitle("POST", for: .normal)
btnPost.addTarget(self, action:#selector(btnPostTapped), for:.touchUpInside)
btnPost.titleLabel?.setFont(Typography.getFont(.PoppinsMedium, size: 12.0), .white)
btnPost.setTitleColor(.menuColor, for: .normal)
btnPost.setTitleColor(.darkGray, for: .highlighted)
btnPost.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnPost)

placeDetailSegmentController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(placeDetailSegmentController, animated: true)
```

where inside `btnPostTapped` method I have wrote following code to dismiss keyboard. But didn't work.

```
@objc func btnPostTapped() {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

> How can I dismiss keyboard from one view controller to another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your code to dismiss keyboard as follows:

```
@objc func btnPostTapped() {
    AppDelegate.shared.window?.endEditing(true)
}
```

Our app's base is `window`, So when you perform any event on window it will affect on whole app. I hope this will fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hide keyboard from anywhere

```
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIApplication.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
```

or

Get the required viewcontroller instance from navigation hierarchy and resign keyboard as:

```
requiredViewController.textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

or

```
requiredViewController.view.endEditing(true)
```